# Porting Adafruit libs from C++ to C

Tags: c++, adafruit

I'm currently trying to port the AdafruitGFX libs from C++ to C (DynamicC for the Rabbit micro).
Can someone help me with this inline function?
I created a .c .h couple and put a prototype for it in the header but still it actually throws a lot of errors... thanks!

```
//GFXFONT.H
    
/// Font data stored PER GLYPH
typedef struct {
  uint16_t bitmapOffset; ///< Pointer into GFXfont->bitmap
  uint8_t width;         ///< Bitmap dimensions in pixels
  uint8_t height;        ///< Bitmap dimensions in pixels
  uint8_t xAdvance;      ///< Distance to advance cursor (x axis)
  int8_t xOffset;        ///< X dist from cursor pos to UL corner
  int8_t yOffset;        ///< Y dist from cursor pos to UL corner
} GFXglyph;

/// Data stored for FONT AS A WHOLE
typedef struct {
  uint8_t *bitmap;  ///< Glyph bitmaps, concatenated
  GFXglyph *glyph;  ///< Glyph array
  uint16_t first;   ///< ASCII extents (first char)
  uint16_t last;    ///< ASCII extents (last char)
  uint8_t yAdvance; ///< Newline distance (y axis)
} GFXfont;

//ADAFRUITGFX.H
inline GFXglyph *pgm_read_glyph_ptr(const GFXfont *gfxFont, uint8_t c);


// .C FILE
#include "AdafruitGFX.h"
#include "glcdfont.c"
#include "gfxfont.h"


#ifndef pgm_read_byte
#define pgm_read_byte(addr) (*(const unsigned char *)(addr))
#endif
#ifndef pgm_read_word
#define pgm_read_word(addr) (*(const unsigned short *)(addr))
#endif
#ifndef pgm_read_dword
#define pgm_read_dword(addr) (*(const unsigned long *)(addr))
#endif

#if !defined(__INT_MAX__) || (__INT_MAX__ > 0xFFFF)
#define pgm_read_pointer(addr) ((void *)pgm_read_dword(addr))
#else
#define pgm_read_pointer(addr) ((void *)pgm_read_word(addr))
#endif


inline GFXglyph *pgm_read_glyph_ptr(const GFXfont *gfxFont, uint8_t c) {
#ifdef __AVR__
  return &(((GFXglyph *)pgm_read_pointer(&gfxFont->glyph))[c]);
#else
  return gfxFont->glyph + c;
#endif //__AVR__
}
```

[errors from the compiler](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ejud9.jpg)

Comment: Is the code snippet from the header or the source file?

Comment: source, I modified the question to include the entire code from header and source, thanks

Comment: The error is complaining about `AdafruitGFX.h` - is that something you wrote?  If not, it may indicate a bug in your preprocessor commands (e.g. an unterminated `#if`, a colliding `#define`, etc.)

Comment: AdafruitGFX.h contains the prototype which I wrote here under gfxfont.h

Comment: This is the major problem: http://prntscr.com/1414l51

Comment: it seems that the problem is the "inline" keyword... if I remove it I can compile succesfully

Comment: What happens if you put the definition in the header file (rather than in the source file)?

Comment: doesn't work :( http://prntscr.com/141ixjl

Comment: Either change your `struct` type names to something that doesn't clash with `GFX...` , which are unconditionally defined by `Adafruit_GFX.h` -> `gfxfont.h`. Or place `#define _GFXFONT_H_` before including the headers to trigger the header guard. Typically, headers should be included before other code / specifications - it's better practice.